# A good way to check various Option objects in Scala

Tags: scala

My question is shown in the following code segment.

```
def myMethod() : Option[Boo] = {
  val f1 = ... // data type: Option[Foo1]
  val f2 = ... // data type: Option[Foo2] 
  val f3 = ... // data type: Option[Foo3]

  // return None if any of the above is None. otherwise return an object Boo
  if(f1.isEmpty || f2.isEmpty || f3.isEmpty)
     return None
  return Boo(f1.get.attr01, f2.get.attr01, f3.get.attr01)
}
```

Any better approaches which take advantage of Option?

Answer (score 4):

Presuming your classes look something like the following:

```
case class Foo1(data: Int)
case class Foo2(data: String)
case class Foo3(data: Double)

case class Boo(d1: Int, d2: String, d3: Double)
```

then you can achieve what you are after with a for comprehension:

```
for {
  d1 <- f1
  d2 <- f2
  d3 <- f3
} yield Boo(d1.data, d2.data, d3.data)
```

or:

```
for {
  d1 <- f1.map(_.data)
  d2 <- f2.map(_.data)
  d3 <- f3.map(_.data)
} yield Boo(d1, d2, d3)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. In my case, the values of those data is from DB and the object Boo created with their attributes of f.

Comment: @TeeKai You should be able to adapt what I've given to match the specifics of your situation.

Answer (score 0):

This is precisely what a for-comprehension does

```
def myMethod() : Option[Boo] = for {
  f1 <- ... // data type: Option[Foo1]
  f2 <- ... // data type: Option[Foo2] 
  f3 <- ... // data type: Option[Foo3]
} yield Boo(f1.attr01, f2.attr01, f3.attr01)
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me know the term so that I can follow up and learn more about Scala.